# Why is the display propety reverting to its default value when I’ve programmed it to do otherwise?

Tags: html, css, display

I have a `<div>` element where I’m trying to change the `display` property to `block`, but whenever I do this the web browser just reverts the value back to `inline-block`.

I’ve tried changing the parent’s `display` to `block` and even the `<div>` element itself to `block` but the browser still reverts the `display` on said `<div>` element back to `inline-block`.

Surely I’m just missing some sort of basic rule here.

Comment: I'm afraid that without more details and a reproducible scenario there simply isn't enough detail in this question for one to go about giving you any sort of an answer.  Maybe review [ask] for some tips on how to update this so that you get better assistance from the community.  Good luck!

Comment: youre changing the property how? js or jquery ?

Comment: inline-block isn't a default. Something else is prioritizing that value and overriding your settings.

Comment: i would try to change it from the dev console of your browser, this way you would see more clearly whats happening

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys, I worked it out.. it's because I had set the display property to inline-block via javascript.. know I know that takes precedence lol